# Problem with Javascript RegExp-mask

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
{theField} > YEAR (today, -3) || {theField}  < YEAR (today, +3)
```

I want it to be replaced into:

```
{theField} > " + YEAR (today, -3) + " || {theField}  < " + YEAR (today, +3) + "
```

I have tried this:

```
String.replace(/(.*)(YEAR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY+)(.*[)]+)/g, "$1 \" + $2 $3 + \"")
```

But that gives me:

```
{theField} > YEAR (today, +3) || {theField}  >  " + YEAR  (today, +3) + "
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `DAY+` matches `DAYYYYYYYY`. Don't know if it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful using greedy matching when you have `.*`. Usually this doesn't do what you want - it matches as much of the string as possible. You either need to use a negative character class to stop matching when you reach a certain character (e.g. `[^)]`) or else use a [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) match `.*?`. Here is how you could do it using the lazy quantifier:

```
s = '{theField} > YEAR (today, -3) || {theField}  < YEAR (today, +3)';
result = s.replace(/((YEAR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY).*?\))/g, '" + $1 + "')
```

Result:

```
{theField} > " + YEAR (today, -3) + " || {theField}  < " + YEAR (today, +3) + "
```

Note that I've cleaned up a bit in your regular expression:

- Removed the `+` from `DAY+` as KennyTM noted
- Changed `[)]+` to `\)`
- Changed the literal replacement string from double-quoted to single-quoted so that the quotes in the replacement text don't need to be escaped
- Removed the extra space you were putting into the result between YEAR and the following opening parenthesis